# Как работает HashMap поиск элемента по хешу?

Tags: java, hashmap

О том как работает HashMap в принципе все понятно. Что такое бандлы, сложность поиска и тд. Все это находится в гугле.

Вопрос в том, как по уже полученному хешу находится нужный элемент в массиве.

Как я понимаю, единственный способ получить время доступа О(1) это массив, обращаясь по индексу. Значит, имея хеш какого-то объекта, необходимо его к этому индексу каким-то образом привести, чтобы по хешу получить все тот же О(1).

Простой вариант приходит в голову, что HashMap просто резервирует массив максимального размера где элементы хранятся под индексами равными самому хешу объекта, но для этого необходимо очень много памяти и такой вариант кажется нереалистичным

Comment: Не вот это случайно? https://habr.com/ru/post/421179/

Comment: @andreymal, да. Спасибо. Я не так хорошо пользуюсь гуглом) Теперь даже не знаю что с вопросом делать

Comment: Ну, так как Stack Overflow стремится быть самодостаточной базой знаний и ответы-ссылки здесь как бы не очень одобряются, может, кто-нибудь ещё и полноценный ответ здесь напишет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть пара важных моментов:

- каждый бандл это колллекция;
- количество этих бандлов это всегда
  степень 2-ки.

Когда элемент помещается в HashMap'у, то делается **дополнительная операция вычисления остатка от деления хэша на количество бандлов**. Этот результат и будет индексом бандла, в который попадёт элемент. Также он никогда не будет больше количества бандлов (*остаток от деления ведь!*)

А учитывая, что количество бандлов это всегда степень 2-ки, то для оптимизации операция деления заменяется операцией **логическое И** (хэш) и (количество бандлов - 1)